# How can i limit the results of this formula to 0 without creating negative numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I limit the results of this formula to 0 without creating negative numbers?

Formula
=IFERROR(((N36-P36)/N36 ), "NA")

it generates values like this [image]

I would like to put a limit that would prevent the formula to create negative numbers like -34 or -1 etc. The lowest result should be 0 not under that. How can I fix it?
Except this the formula works as intended

Comment: Welcome to the community. Googling "excel prevent negative numbers" (w/o quotes) brought this as the first result: [Negative Numbers to Zero](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/negative-numbers-to-zero.html). Looks pretty bang on. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how SE communities differ from discussion boards. For example you should search for the answer first - you'll often get it faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `IF` test to the calculation itself:

```
=IFERROR(  IF( ((N36-P36)/N36)<0, 0, ((N36-P36)/N36) ), "NA")
```

Done this way, if the calculation produces a numerical result AND it is negative, the output is a 0. And if it produces an error, the output is still "NA" so you have everything you want.

*(Probably the Comment's search result URL will be good for... decades... as the site is well-known, but who knows? I'm very sure (so sure it's not even worth clicking it) that it suggests the same thing, and if it doesn't, well, then you'll have more ways. But the above is about as straightforward as it gets.)*

Comment: In this context, `MAX()` works the same as `IF()` but is shorter

Comment: That's amazing. It works! Thanks.